# Why does my does my dropdown menu not work when I combine it with a basic background image?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, background-image

Hi guys I'm an absolute beginner who just started learning html and was wondering why when I try to add a background image to my html file my dropdown menu suddenly becomes inoperative. These first and second pieces of code are my attempts at using a background image and a dropdown menu respectively. They both work fine for learning purposes but in the third piece of code when I combine them the dropdown button doesn't activate when hovered over. Anyone understand why?

**BACKGROUND IMAGE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
    background-image: url('https://i2.wp.com/brandikaran.com/wp-content/uploads/ld.png?ssl=1');
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Testing</h2>

    <p>Work this time pls</p>
  </body>
    </html>
```

**DROPDOWN MENU CODE**

```
!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <<title>Dropdown Menus</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16 px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: pink;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: OrangeRed;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>


  <div class="Dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">S Tier</a>
      <a href="#">A Tier</a>
      <a href="#">B Tier</a>
      </div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

**COMBINING THEM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body {
    background-image: url('https://i2.wp.com/brandikaran.com/wp-content/uploads/ld.png?ssl=1');
  }

  .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16 px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: pink;}

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: OrangeRed;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Testing</h2>

    <p>Work this time pls</p>
    <div class="Dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">S Tier</a>
        <a href="#">A Tier</a>
        <a href="#">B Tier</a>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does your browser’s Developer Tools’ Network tab say?

Comment: Looks like you didn't close your Dropdown `<div>` tag.

Comment: @Dai I've never used that inspection tool before but for the record it's completely empty. Should be empty if the only element that needs to be networked is the image I'm using for the background? The background image is working fine though. The issue is the dropdown menu that doesn't work.

Comment: @alexRummel I closed those tags and the hover function still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your "combined" code in a JSFiddle snippet and it ran fine (I did manually add an extra `</div>` closing tag). I suspect the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error here, change the first div class name to dropdown from Dropdown. It will work.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">S Tier</a>
      <a href="#">A Tier</a>
      <a href="#">B Tier</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And also the div container is not closed properly, but that shouldn't be a problem here, because the browser will take care of that automatically, but make sure you close all the tags properly, inproper closing may lead to unexcepted result. Thank you

Comment: Omg thank you. A single capitalized letter made all the difference.